# L5 : Changing the redirection after a login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I want to change the redirections after login/logout.

In my `Auth/AuthController`I defined

```
protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/';
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

The logout route is good : root, but login rectirection is still `/home`....

And using `protected $redirectPath ='/'`doesn't resolve my problem

Comment: Try `redirectPath` instead of `redirectTo`, I doubt it'll do anything, but the `RedirectsUsers` [trait](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RedirectsUsers.php) appears to prefer this over `redirectTo`. But yeah, the first thing it will do is try to redirect you to the place you were originally intending to go, so if you went to `/home` and got redirected to the login page, it'll redirect you back to home after login by default, see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L86).

Comment: I have no /home route and I deleted the HomeController :) And as I wrote, I tried the 2 properties and no one is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **RedirectIfAuthenticated**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

    if ($this->auth->check())
    {
        return new RedirectResponse(url('/'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware try setting redirect path in following function,

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->check())
    {
        return new RedirectResponse(url('/home'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

This basically checks if `user` is logged in redirect to `home`

Comment: I modified the handle() method `   return redirect(route('/'));` and now I have the error Route [/] not defined.`..... In routes.php i have Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');``

Comment: `route()` refers to a named route. I.e.

`Route::get('/', ['as' => 'homepage', 'uses' => 'SomeController@home']);`

with

`route('homepage');` would work. You can just use `url('/')` if you don't want to name the route.

Comment: @Lolo please see Ben's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

In `AuthController`, adding 2 functions `getLogout` and `postLogin` which will handle `login/logout` requests. After that, Laravel will handle magic for you.

```
 public function postLogin(Request $req){
    //Validate input
    $this->validate($req,[
        'email' => 'required', 'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    $credentials = $req->only('email','password');

    if($this->auth->attempt($credentials,$req->has('remember'))){
        return redirect('articles');
    }
    return redirect('auth/login')
                ->withInput($req->only('email'))
                ->withErrors([
                    'email' => 'Something wrong'
                ]);
}

 public function getLogout(){
    $this->auth->logout();
    return redirect('articles');
}
```

Comment: I tried and even by doing `return redirect('/');`I go to `/home`

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of the login post handler redirects to the URL which the user intended to visit before being redirected to the login page.

If Laravel is unable to find the intended URL it passes in the output of  `redirectPath()` from the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait, below:

```
/**
 * Get the post register / login redirect path.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath'))
    {
        return $this->redirectPath;
    }

    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
}
```

As you an see, it looks for properties `redirectPath` and `redirectTo`. I'm not sure why there are both; perhaps for BC with an older version.

Setting either of these properties in your controller should suffice. That said, you should also be able to overwrite this method in your controller if you'd like to implement it differently.

One thing to note is that this method is only called if Laravel can't find the intended url/path. If for example you visit `/home` and are redirected to the login page, `/home` is your intended URL and therefore you'll be redirected there.

The only way to force this is to either replace the implementation of postController by overwriting the method in your controller, or perhaps set the `url.intended` session variable first.

```
// Obviously add namespaces and use statements 

class AuthController extends Controller {
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers {
        postLogin as traitPostLogin;
    }

    protected $redirectTo = 'some-page';

    function postLogin(Request $request) {
      session('url.intended', $this->redirectTo);

      return $this->traitPostLogin($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not workin..... still tryin to reach /home. I someone can explain me why it works for logout method but not for login ?

Comment: Do you have `/` set up as a guest-only route? If you do, then the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware will be kicking in and, as pinkal vansia and 2318 allude to, defaulting to `/home`, which can be changed in that middleware in your `app` directory.

Comment: of course !! The route WORKS for logout, then should works for login